# Angular Kendo Grid with DropDown and ReactiveForm

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-dropdown

I have a kendo Grid, which I have cut down for simplicity:

```
<kendo-grid
  [data]="customerTypes | async"
  [height]="700"
  [pageSize]="state.take"
  [skip]="state.skip"
  [sort]="state.sort"
  [pageable]="false"
  [sortable]="true"
  (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)"
  (edit)="editHandler($event)"
  (cancel)="cancelHandler($event)"
  (save)="saveHandler($event)"
  (remove)="removeHandler($event)"
  (add)="addHandler($event)"
  [navigable]="true"
>
  <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
    <button [primary]="true" kendoGridAddCommand>Add new</button>
  </ng-template>

<kendo-grid-column field="customertype" title="Customer Type" width="450">
  
  <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate
    let-dataItem="dataItem"
    let-column="column"
    let-formGroup="formGroup">

    <kendo-dropdownlist
    [defaultItem]="'Select Customer Type...'"
    [data]="customerTypesList"
    [formControl]="formGroup.get('customertype')"
  ></kendo-dropdownlist>

  </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>

  <kendo-grid-command-column title="Commands" width="220">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-isNew="isNew">
      <button kendoGridEditCommand [primary]="true">Edit</button>
      <button kendoGridRemoveCommand>Remove</button>
      <button kendoGridSaveCommand [disabled]="formGroup?.invalid">
        {{ isNew ? "Add" : "Update" }}
      </button>
      <button kendoGridCancelCommand>
        {{ isNew ? "Discard changes" : "Cancel" }}
      </button>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-command-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

In the component, I have a list that populates the drop down:

```
  public customerTypesList = [
    'Customer 1',
    'Customer 2'
  ];
```

I also have the `addHandler` to create the `FormGroup`:

```
 public addHandler({ sender }) {
    this.closeEditor(sender);

    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(),
      custnumber: new FormControl(''),
      customerlongname: new FormControl(''),
      customershortname: new FormControl(''),
      customertype: new FormControl('')
    });

    sender.addRow(this.formGroup);
  }
```

And the `saveHandler` looks like this:

```
public saveHandler({ sender, rowIndex, formGroup, isNew }) {
    const customerType: ICustomerType = formGroup.value;
    this.editService.save(this.uri, customerType, isNew);

    sender.closeRow(rowIndex);
  }
```

When I populate the other fields when adding a new record, and select the Customer Type, I add a break to the `saveHandler` to inspect the `formGroup.value`, and all fields are populated except for the customerType and I can't see why - I think I'm missing a binding somewhere?

Comment: It'd be nice if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I assume this is about [Teleriks grid editing](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-reactive-forms/). You could compare that example to yours and modify it to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hard to tell w/o a running sample, but my guess is that the `[formControlName]="'customertype'"` is not working properly because it would require the FormGroup to be bound to a parent element. You might want to try something along those lines `[formControl]="formGroup.get('customertype')"`

Comment: @MikeS.  - I'll try and add a working version

Comment: @Philipp - I have tried that too, I have tried quite a few combinations.

Answer (score 1):

I will add this here in case it helps anyone else.  Since I was testing this using Chrome Tools, I was not getting any of the typical errors, modules missing etc. So, I assumed everything was loaded correctly.  I double-checked the module, and I was missing `ReactiveFormsModule`.  So, although I was using the control as a Reactive Form, the module wasn't loaded, but I wasn't getting any error to indicate this - the fix:

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...,
    ReactiveFormsModule
    ]
})
export class NameModule { }
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I just lost one hour to exactly this issue. The actual error was totally misleading (Can't bind to ... not a known property)